# how to find ancestors in XML using XQuery-sql

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql, xquery

I'm working with some xml columns and I use XQuery to find the first nearest ancestor (B) of a specific child (child E) but this error occurs:

> Msg 9335, Level 16, State 1, Line 16 XQuery [query()]: The XQuery
>   syntax 'ancestor' is not supported.

The depth level of ancestors and the descendants is not static and I want the result to be "B2"
I have tried

```
    DECLARE @x xml
SET @x = CAST(
'<A>
    <B name="B1">
        <C>
            <B id="1" name="B2">
                <D id="1.1" name="D1">
                    <E id="1" />
                    <E id="2" />
                </D>
            </B>
        </C>
    </B>    
</A>' AS xml)

SELECT @x.query('data(//E/ancestor::B[1]/@name)')
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: Do you know, how many levels between B and E?

Comment: no I 've no idea and it's differant
thanks for your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using a different approach to avoid having to call `ancestor` axis, for example :

```
SELECT @x.query('data(//B[.//E][not(.//B)]/@name)')
```

**brief explanation regarding the predicates being used :**

- `[.//E]` : ensure that the target `B` elements have descendant element(s) `E`
- `[not(.//B)]` : ensure that the target `B` elements don't have descendant element(s) `B`, in other words the target `B` element has to be the inner-most `B` element having descendant `E`

Comment: @SarahAllen don't forget to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it solved the problem in question. Thanks

Comment: sorry I didn't know how to accept
thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @h int

DECLARE @x xml
SET @x = CAST(
'<A>
    <B name="B1">
        <C>
            <B id="1" name="B2">
                <D id="1.1" name="D1">
                    <E id="1" />
                    <E id="2" />
                </D>
            </B>
        </C>
    </B>    
</A>' AS xml)

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @h OUTPUT, @x

SELECT eId, bName
FROM OPENXML(@h, '//E', 2)
WITH 
(
    eId varchar(5) '@id', 
    bName varchar(5) 'ancestor::B[1]/@name')

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @h
```